# Angularjs : single object from array of JSON objects to be returned based on condition

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an object that contains the objects array. Given as:

```js
var storedetails = {
  "stores": {
    "store1": [{
        "pno": 1,
        "pname": "Lux",
        "stock": "100",
        "cost": 10,
        "discount": 10,
        "details": "this is lux"
      },
      {
        "pno": 2,
        "pname": "Rexona",
        "stock": "200",
        "cost": 20,
        "discount": 20,
        "details": "this is Rexona"
      }
    ],
    "store2": [{
        "pno": 3,
        "pname": "Dove",
        "stock": "300",
        "cost": 30,
        "discount": 30,
        "details": "this is Dove"
      },
      {
        "pno": 4,
        "pname": "Lifebouy",
        "stock": "400",
        "cost": 40,
        "discount": 40,
        "details": "this is LifeBouy"
      }
    ],
    "store3": [{
      "pno": 5,
      "pname": "Dettol",
      "stock": "300",
      "cost": 50,
      "discount": 50,
      "details": "this is Dettol"
    }]
  }
}
```

I wanted based on PNO (product number), objects need to retrieved and can be rendered to AngularJS page. How to retrieve that object?

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop around the objects would do.

```
var t = storedetails.stores;
function getProduct(storeName, pId){
var p; 
angular.forEach(t[storeName], function(product, index){ 
    console.log(product.pno, pId); 
    if(product.pno === pId) 
    {
        console.log("===========");
        p=product; 
    } 
}) 
return p;
}
```

Now calling simply the function `getProduct("store1", 1)` would give the result of the product id 1 from the store1 object

Update

```
function getProduct(pId){
var p; 
angular.forEach(t, function(storeName, i){
    angular.forEach(storeName, function(product, index){ 
        if(product.pno === pId) 
        {
            p=product; 
        } 
    }) 
})
return p;
}
```

Comment: thanks Neswine ,but my input will be ProductID that is pno and i have to get the object back as output.

Comment: Please find the updated function. and please do upvote it it helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProd(pId) {
            var p;
            angular.forEach($rootScope.storedetails, function (storeName, i) {
                angular.forEach(storeName, function (product, index) {
                    angular.forEach(product, function (productdet, index) {
                    //debugger
                    if (productdet.pno === pId) {
                        p = productdet;
                    }
                })
                })
            })
            return p;
        }
```